# Class 'Facebook' not found error message

Tags: php, facebook

i copied some html code for a facebook application but i seem to get the following error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in /home/content/73/7931773/html/facebook-app/index.php
```

Well i do the following at the place where i call the api

```
require 'facebook.php';

/**
 * Create an application instance on Facebook developers.
 * Replace with your own values.
 */
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '***',
  'secret' => '***',
  'cookie' => true,
));
```

1 . What is the significane of facebook.php . i dont see it in the facebook developers library .

2 . how do i get rid of this error .

i think i need to include something though i cant seem to figure out what ?

Comment: I've edited out your facebook credentials, but they'll still be in the edit history on the site, available to any moderators. I suggest you go to Facebook and invalidate those and get new one issued immediately.

Comment: Do you have the base_facebook.php file in the directory ?

Comment: what's in `facebook.php`

Comment: @alex @robert i realise the problem . i should have the facebook.php in the exact same directory .

Comment: i read in an article that my directory structure should be like the following your_path_to_modules_/fbconnect/facebook-client/facebook.php
your_path_to_modules_/fbconnect/facebook-client/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php
your_path_to_modules_/fbconnect/facebook-client/jsonwrapper/jsonwrapper.php
your_path_to_modules_/fbconnect/facebook-client/jsonwrapper/jsonwrapper_inner.php
your_path_to_modules_/fbconnect/facebook-client/jsonwrapper/JSON/JSON.php

Comment: the article said i can pick up the files from the following location http://svn.facebook.com/svnroot/platform/clients/packages/facebook-platform.tar.gz . however this link does not seem to work . Can someone guide me to the place from where i cn download these files . Sorry i am tottaly new to this !:(

Answer (score 2):

That facebook call belongs to the Facebook PHP SDK. It instantiates the facebook class. You are getting the error probably because you dont have the facebook.php in the same folder as your script.

To get rid of the error. Either remove facebook object from your application or get the facebook class.

Here is the link. https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

Comment: that link was pointing to a older version. Try this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

Answer (score 2):

I got this error and found it was caused by "Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension" at root. Installing CURL for PHP fixed it.

Comment: this is a worth 1000 words sentence solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

The error you get just means that the class `Facebook` does not exists. Therefore you can create an instance of it like in this line of code:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
```

The require statement of the *facebook.php* file suggests that it might provide the class definition of the `Facebook` class. Obviously it does not. So if you ask

> 1 . What is the significane of facebook.php

This can not be properly answered as your question does not provide any information about that file at all.

> 2 . how do i get rid of this error .

You get rid of this error by providing the class definition of the `Facebook` class prior to creating a new object instance. The other way would be to not create an instance of the `Facebook` class at all. This will remove the error as well. However I think that is not intended by you. So just include all files needed and you should be fine to go.

To do this, locate the Facebook API on your disk. Then put the full path into the require statement to that file.

*ZIP* and *TAR.GZ* files of the API can be downloaded on the [Facebook PHP-SDK Download Page](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/downloads). The files in question are in the `src` sub-folder therein.

Comment: thanks . I do realise what i am missing . I dont have the intended files . i need to have the facebook-client/facebook.php file in the same directory . an article i read pointed me to download these from http://svn.facebook.com/svnroot/platform/clients/packages/facebook-platform.tar.gz . However this surely does not work . Where can i get these files . ? can u share a location from wher i can download these .

Comment: Sure, download https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/zipball/v3.0.1 and extract the `src` folder therein. It contains the files you need.

Comment: @rockstar If any of the answers helped you out or correctly answered your question, you might want to think about [accepting them as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$facebook_appid='';

$facebook_app_secret='';

$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => $facebook_appid,'secret' => $facebook_app_secret,));

?>
```