# Nginx | Cakephp | Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, nginx, cakephp-2.0

```
Debian Squeeze | PHP 5.4.33 | nginx: 1.6.2 | Cakephp 2.5.x
```

Current code works on Apache Config but not on Nginx

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Facebook', array('file' => 'facebook'. DS .'facebook.php'));

$this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => Configure::read("FB_APP_ID"),
    'secret' => Configure::read("FB_APP_SECRET"),
))
```

Also Tried

```
require_once APP . 'Vendor' . DS .'facebook'. DS .'facebook.php';
```

But still gives the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in /***/**.... on line **
```

FacebookSDK is inside app/Vendor

Nginx Config : http://pastebin.com/pAxwJXFX

Works on the Apache, but not on Nginx

Comment: does the file exists on the `APP . 'Vendor' . DS .'facebook'. DS .'facebook.php'`?

Comment: Yes, It does exists, and the same stuff is working when I run Apache Server.

Comment: Possible rewrite issue IMO. Where do you keep the 'Facebook' class ? Is it <root>/Vendor or is it <root>/app/Vendor ? Nginx config would be helpful.

Comment: FacebookSDK is inside **app/Vendor**
Nginx Config added in main Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19391688/977070

Just needed to install php5-curl

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```