# Facebook Class Not Found

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I call the Facebook it says Facebook Class Not Found. I'm using the following code:

```
<?php

//include the Facebook PHP SDK
include_once 'Facebook/Facebook.php';

//instantiate the Facebook library with the APP ID and APP SECRET
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => '',
    'secret' => '',
    'cookie' => true
)); ?>
```

The exact error I get:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\connect.php on line 7
```

The include_once location of the file is correct, I've tried changing its location and it does give error when there's no file present in the destination, but on this code the include_once is okay and is including the file yet it's not loading the classes. I've even tried using **Facebook/autoload.php** but it doesn't help either.

Not sure whats wrong

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19391688/1740715

Comment: I have all the files of the Facebook SDK, saw that a while ago too, didn't help.